# Mouse location out of sync on tabs

Tags: bug, new-nav

First I will admit this is a pretty hard issue to reproduce.
Given some pretty specific mouse movement I was able to have my mouse hovered over a custom tab for the C# tag while the page still thought the mouse was hovered over active and actually clicking would indeed use this false mouse position.

My tab set up is:

- home
- voted
- active
- c#

Steps to reproduce:

1. Mouse on home tab
2. Move mouse horizontally towards C# tab
3. Pause mouse on the down arrow of active for <1 second
4. Continue to C# tab
5. Hover style will remain on Active and the down arrow for <strike>~1 second before switching to the C# tab</strike> bad state remains until mouse moves, I'm just bad at holding my mouse still.

Mouse movement between steps 2 and 3 needs to be quick, when the bug occurs I see the hover style for the active down arrow activate almost at the same time (if not before) that of the active tab.

Here is a screenshot I managed to capture while in the bad state.
Obviously the cursor can't be seen but you can see that the active tooltip is out of place.

[image: Screenshot of bad state]

Browser version: Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m